# Naming variables postgresql ruby rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was creating variables with digits inside

```
day_1, day_2, day_3 [...]
```

and rails complained.  Maybe I misread the error message. Maybe it is because I started initially naming them 1-Day, 2_day [...] (don't really recall).  But when I went and created the variables with characters

```
day_one, day_two, day_three [...]
```

rails did not complain.  I figured it might be a convention within the PostgreSQL, ruby, rails stack. It turns out that using character counters is messy because conversions such as with the numbers_to_words gem then get caught up in i18n active locale issues.  Definitely prefer avoiding them!

Weeks later, cluelessly, I created a set of variables with digits inside, just as above.  And they're running properly.

Having a hard time finding documentation for this matter.
So what are the rules, conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different variants having been tested, I conclude that :

- a digit CANNOT start a stored variable's name;
- within it, or at its   end, creates no issues.

Comment: Yes, the syntax error that is raised in VIM is that it is expecting a keyword "end". In IRB it is complaining about an unexpected end of input. That implies that when you start off with a number it is expecting a block. Which makes sense if you think of having to parse something like this: ```5.times { |x|... }```. Ruby is expecting a block to follow.

Comment: Ah, this is useful.  It clarifies the issue outright.